# Renegotiation errors in Webrtc during audio to video call upgrade

Tags: webrtc

I have a WebRTC application that works as follows:

1. Caller creates peer connection, creates (audio only) offer, sets local description, and sends (audio only) offer to Callee.
2. Callee sets remote description, creates answer, sets local description, and sends answer to Caller.
3. Caller sets remote description.
4. Caller and Callee can successfully communicate.(An audio call is established.)
5. Caller adds the videoTracks to the localStream, creates offer , sets local description, and sends (audio+video) offer to Callee.
6. Callee adds the videoTracks,sets remote description, creates answer, sets local description and sends answer to Caller.
7. Caller sets remote description.

In Chrome, all the steps are successful, but there is no remote Video either at the Caller or at the Callee. Both Caller and Callee have local video. onAddTrack event is fired. The remote stream is then used to attach to the video DOM element.But there is white screen displayed. After this when the Callee removes video and adds video, then remote Video is displayed at both ends.

But this works fine when there is a video call established and either callee or caller remove/add video.

When onAddTrack() is fired (for the first time when video is added to an audio call), the video track is muted and readyState property is also 'muted';eventhough when the videoTracks were added, the enable property is set to true, muted is false and readyState is live.

Comment: without a dump from chrome://webrtc-internals its somewhat hard to say what goes wrong.

See also https://github.com/opentok/upgrade-test/blob/master/test/test.js for a working implementation

Comment: Thank you, But  found that the remote video tracks are muted although neither Caller nor the Callee muted the video tracks

Comment: Did you get the solution for the problem mentioned?

Comment: Not yet, I have filed a bug which is merged with https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=705901